# JavaScript toggle/swap

Tags: javascript

How to toggle values in javascript? For example, if x = apple, then function should return x = orange. If x = orange, then function should return x = apple.
Not sure, what works here, toggle or swap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an if/else clause:

```
    toggleFruit(x) {
      if (x === 'apple') {
         x = 'orange';
      } else {
         x = 'apple';
      }
      return x;
    }
```

or with a ternary operator

```
  toggleFruit(x){
       return x = x === 'apple' ? 'orange' : 'apple'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to do it without using if/else?

Comment: Yep, that's the seconds part of my answer. It's basically the same, but without an if/else. Edited the answer so it's more understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers to this approach. If you only want to toggle values, than this might be a solution you're seeking.

```
var fruit = 'red';
var fruits = ['orange', 'red'];

var opposite = fruits[fruit === fruits[0] & 1];
console.log(opposite);
```

Answer (score 0):

A ternary operator should be good here.

```
    function toggleFruit(x) {
        return x === apple ? orange : apple
    }
```